# xslt: compare two list variables

Tags: xslt

I am using saxon 9.0, xslt version 2.

If at least one item is comman in the two lists then the output should be 1 otherwise output should be 0.

```
<xsl:variable name="var_1" select="tokenize("apple mango grape" ' ')"/>
<xsl:variable name="var_2" select="tokenize("cat cow dog", ' ')"/>


<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$var_1 in $var_2">
<xsl:value-of select="1"/>
</xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="0"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

**Exapmple 1:**

var_1 = 'apple', 'mango', 'grape'

var_2 = 'apple', 'cat'

Expected result: 1

**Example 2:**

var_1 = 'apple', 'mango', 'grape'

var_2 = 'app', 'man'

Expected result: 0

**Example 3:**

var_1 = 'apple', 'mango', 'grape'

var_2 = 'grape', 'apple', 'mango'

Expected result: 1

Anybody help me getting these expected results.

Thanks
SRB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If at least one item is comman in the two lists then the output should be 1 otherwise output should be 0.

That's pretty-well exactly what the XPath "=" operator does.

It's simply

```
xs:integer($var1 = $var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would solve it is by breaking one of the variables into a list and then use `contains` to look for it in the other list.

Then have this list of the results of `contain` checked to see if it "contains" a `true` case and return `true` if it does, and `false` if it doesn't

So it will be something like this:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="tokenize("apple mango grape" ' ')>
  <xsl:if test="contains(text(), 'apple cow dog')">
    1
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Shortcoming, the word app will also be found in the string `apple cow dog` so I suggest you wrap your words with `~` or similar, so that you also look for `~app~` rather than `app`.

Comment: The string var_1 'apple mango grape' and var_2 comes from the attribute of an xml file. This file is being used by many other people and hence i do not have much control over it. As per your suggestion I should generate another 2 lists by appending ~ to each of the items in the var_1 and var_2. Then perform the comparison as per your code. Am I right?    Thanks, SRB

Comment: Yes, append ~, or just replace ` ` with `~ ~` and add one `~` at the start, and one at the end. Then tokenize

Comment: After replacing the ' ' with '~', <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($var_1 ,'~')>
      <xsl:if test="contains(text(), $var_2)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each> In the above code can we use anything else instead of text(). Because the output files are not created with this code. It fails on running xslt and no error message displayed.   Thanks, SRB

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid, otherwise it *would* work as you expect:

```
<xsl:variable name="var_1" select="tokenize('apple mango grape', ' ')"/>
<xsl:variable name="var_2" select="tokenize('cat cow dog', ' ')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<result>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$var_1 = $var_2">
        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</result>

</xsl:template>
```

returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>0</result>
```

while:

```
<xsl:variable name="var_1" select="tokenize('apple mango grape', ' ')"/>
<xsl:variable name="var_2" select="tokenize('cat cow mango dog', ' ')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<result>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$var_1 = $var_2">
        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</result>

</xsl:template>
```

returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>1</result>
```